# Get link from "Join Game" in Steam

Tags: steam

You can join someone's lobby via opened profile, there is a join button which is like steam://joinlobby/*game*/*idlobby*/*idprofile*
(ex: steam://joinlobby/1234/10977524212345124125/76561194214123124).

But if profile closed u cant get that link. Overwise if this is your friend u can click his name and there is a link "Join game" how can i get what is inside? (link to join lobby like steam:// .. ).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Steam API offers the lobby ID for some games, but not all. Even when the Join Game button works fine, the API sometimes fails to list the lobby. I still don't understand why this isn't consistent.

https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=[YourSteamApiKey]&format=json&steamids=[SteamIDs]

For example...

```
"steamid": "76561198042525022",
"gameextrainfo": "Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare - Multiplayer",
"gameid": "209660",
"lobbysteamid": "109775242686656982",
```

Creates...

```
steam://joinlobby/209660/109775242686656982/76561198042525022
```

Which can then be used to compose a Join Game link. Such a link could appear many places to help gather multiplayer lobbies together: Discord, TeamSpeak, Websites, Forums, Chat Bots, etc.

For games where it works, this could have a profound affect on multiplayer games, even reviving dead games simply by helping people play together without first being friends.

Answer (score -2):

if the profile is not private, you can open someone's profile, find green button saying `Join game` under `ingame`, right click on it and select `copy link address`.